# How do I best setup Directory Services in a Linux-only environment (Ubuntu Server 20.04.01)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain, gateway

## SITUATION:

I am setting up a Linux only environment, (two, maybe; SOHO and home system), where I am quite certain that their will be no Windows machines taking part in domain services, (short of guests needing DHCP/DNS and Internet access). In addition to the server (on bare metal), there will be one desktop, and two laptops, (plus three VM servers running on the desktop, one for production, web-based, ERP/CRM/CMS, (plus accompanying RDBMS), one for staging CMS updates, and a sandbox for testing system updates before sending to production server).  The only other devices which I know might possibly be considered for taking part, are two Chromebooks (which might possibly use a shared printer), and three Android phones (which are even less likely to use domain services).

All any other devices may need is DHCP/DNS & Internet. This includes WiFi APs, “Smart home” IoT, such as Google Mini, Chromecast, Smart-sockets/switches, alarm, IP surveillance cameras/NVR, et al.

Currently, my ERP/CRM/CMS apps authenticate against users in the appropriate MariaDB/PostgreSQL databases. MariaDB admin authenticates against itself, (MySQL database tables, or MyPHPAdmin database tables), while PostgreSQL admin authenticates against the local UNIX user login, (which means SSH'ing into the machine first; no web interface).

Configuring/managing users for the applications currently occur on an app-by-app, user-by-user basis, with each app user listed in the app's database. Most apps can have users authenticated against RADIUS, Kerberos, or LDAP services, instead.

### HARDWARE

The server box is an old HP Compaq dc7700 SFF 64-bit Pentium D with 2 GiB RAM. (It was one, but I upgraded it). Also, 80GB HDD. BIOS only, (no UEFI). It originally was running WinXP Pro, but, somehow, someone had managed to install Dell Windows Vista Business OEM on it. Onboard Intel video & GbEth NIC.

What did they used to say? “Linux! Because a 386 is a terrible thing to waste.” ;-)

## RESEARCH

So far, everything I am looking at, (including Ubuntu sites), seems to be telling me how to either use Windows Server AD and connect Linux boxes to it, (**not** happening), or use Samba4 as AD and connect Windows boxes to it, (which I keep getting told is the “easy” and “standard” way, as it handles everything). I am actually familiar with both those techniques, and not interested in installing things which I do not need. I am more interested in a Linux (or even BSD) F/LOSS solution, using OpenLDAP and whatever supporting services necessary.

From my own reading and understanding, I would need to separately install/configure all of the following;…

1. DHCP (isc-dhcp-server)
2. DNS (bind9, dnsutils)
3. LDAP (OpenLDAP → slapd, ldap-utils)
4. Kerberos (krb5-kdc/krb5-kdc-ldap, krb5-admin-server, [schema2ldif, for krb5-kdc-ldap])
5. TLS (gnutls-bin, ssl-cert) [to prevent clear-text transmission of passwords]
6. CUPS [for printer sharing, on the print server]
7. NFS (nfs-kernel-server) [for file-sharing/networked home directories, on the file server]
8. LAMP server (apache2, mariadb-server, php, et al) [for web-interface administration, if needed]
9. OpenSSH (for CLI administration if needed]
10. OpenVPN [only to access my web-based ERP/CRM remotely with a Linux laptop]

(…and, of course, any other services deemed necessary, such as RADIUS, et al).

## CONCERNS

I am told that that this ten-step option will be a royal pain to configure/administer. I am also told that there are other options, such as distros specifically designed for such tasks, but I wanted to keep all servers/desktops/laptops on the same platform (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

Why not Samba4? My understanding is that there are some applications which can authenticate with LDAP, but the LDIF schema used in the MS AD/Samba4 AD LDAP is not adequate for them, and will fail, while OpenLDAP is not compatible with MS/Samba4 AD, (except when in NT4 PDC/BDC mode, which is not recommended).

## QUESTIONS:

1. Is the ten-step program really the only way to go on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (if I am avoiding Samba4)?
2. Is there an administration app for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (aside from Samba4) which makes the ten-step program simpler to implement/administer?

In responses, unless there is some neat trick of which one would love to educate me, one can ignore the Chromebooks and smartphones as part of the domain.

Comment: Take a look at freeIPA/redhat directory server. I wouldn't go with samba for a pure Linux environment.

Comment: I second freeipa. It’s a service specifically for Unix-like authentication and authorization.

Comment: So I gather, then, that question ③ is answered as, “definitely avoid Samba4 NT4 DC for a Linux-only environment,” and question ④ is answered as, “FreeIPA/RHDS.” That still leaves questions ① —the primary question— and ②, the one which will need answering, regardless of the answer to ①.

Any suggestions there? (And should I edit my question to remove questions ③ & ④?

Comment: Moving on a little farther…. I was given PHPldapAdmin as a good tool to administer OpenLDAP. That was actually simple enough. Any other ideas?

Also, how does that compare to GOsa²?